# Migrate old mySQL/RH to new mySQL/Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, migrate

We have a hardware problem with an old mySQL server, and would like to migrate this server to new hardware. The old one is mySQL 3.8 or 4, running Red Hat Linux... from about 2004. We're thinking we'd migrate to Ubuntu Server 12.04 or thereabouts,and to the current version of mySQL. 
There are no changes to the database schema. I was thinking that we'd have mySQL up and running on the new server, then do a mySQLdump to transfer the table data.

1. Would this work? (searching SO I've seen references incremental upgrades from one version of mySQL to the next to get to the revision that you want....however we're moving to new hardware.
2. Since most of the interaction with this database is via PHP, I'm assuming any PHP code will need to be updated as well, can anyone confirm?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this should work just fine. But you need to test it before relying on it for a deployed system. MySQL 3.8 and MySQL 4 are *extremely* obsolete. Countless things have changed since 2004. Some of the changes (3.x to 4.0, 4.0 to 4.1, 4.x to 5.0, to name a few) were *huge*. The only way to know for sure if anything breaks is to try the import and find out. You can do this very easily using a virtual server, like through VirtualBox.
2. That depends.

(a) If your PHP code also hasn't been updated since 2004, yes, you probably need to change a lot of things. For example, the `mysql_*` functions are now obsolete and deprecated; all references to those functions should be replaced with [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

(b) If your PHP code is current for PHP 5.4 or 5.5, you should be fine without rewriting anything. But again, *test evreything* before relying on it on a deployed system.